# Stylesheet_link_tag :all versus :media =>all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

I created a new Rails application from a scaffold, but the tutorial claims the following will appear:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

while I got:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    :all %>
```

What is the difference between them? Which should I use? Why?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

will include the stylesheet named **application.css**, you can have files like **application.css.sass** or **application.css.scss** or any other extensions and rails will compile the css file with the right stylesheet engine and serve the application.css file.

The attribute **"media=all"** is actually a css attribute, which means that the css will be included for all the medias, like when browsing the website, when printing the screen, etc. You can find more information about the media attribute on [this link.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

By using

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    :all %>
```

you will include all the stylesheets that you have on your **app/assets/stylesheets** directory.

You can find more information on [this link.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag)

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [api docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag). Here you have some quote from it:

```
stylesheet_link_tag :all # =>
  <link href="/stylesheets/style1.css"  media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/stylesheets/styleB.css"  media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/stylesheets/styleX2.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


stylesheet_link_tag "style", :media => "all" # =>
  <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Not sure where you got your example from the link you posted does not actually generate the `type` attribute

Comment: Did you notice that the answer was given 5+ years ago? ;)

Comment: @MarcinPietraszek The age of an answer is irrelevant; if it doesn't work, that should be made clear to readers. If it needs updating to reflect changing environments, a comment is appropriate. If you don't want to remain responsible for an answer, you may mark it as a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

The second one not about media type, it's mean include all .css from stylesheets directory on non asset pipeline project.

```
stylesheet_link_tag :all # =>
<link href="/stylesheets/style1.css"  media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/styleB.css"  media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/styleX2.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

stylesheet_link_tag also accepts a parameter for the media attribute in the generated

```
 < %= stylesheet_link_tag :media => "all" %>
```

Will produce:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/killer.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If, instead, you want to include all the stylesheets in the stylesheets directory, just call:

```
< %= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
```

from the rails wiki:

> Notice that stylesheet_link_tag will, by default, search for
>   stylesheets in the /public/stylesheets directory of your application.
>   Also, when no other parameters are passed to stylesheet_link_tag, the
>   type attribute is set to text/css, media is set to screen, and
>   relationship is set to stylesheet. Furthermore, you don't have to
>   include the .css extension in the filename when passing the filename
>   parameter. You're welcome to include it, but as long as your CSS
>   stylesheets are named with the .css extension, there's no need to do
>   so. Note that if you include a file extension, Rails will no longer
>   look for a file with the .css extension for this call. For instance,
>   if you want to include a stylesheet named my_style.new.css, the
>   following is not sufficient: