# Not able to include external stylesheet in rails application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I have *style.css* file in my *assets/stylesheets* directory and in the html I'm using`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/stylesheets/style.css" %>`. I tried inspect element to check it, and css file is not being included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your problem has the hallmarks of a Rails asset pipeline problem

1. Do you have an application.css.erb with something like this? It's created by default and serves as the backbone for the CSS aspect of the asset pipeline in rails.

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

2. Using the asset pipeline means that a call like "/stylesheets/style.css" would never be valid in production and should be avoided in code.

If you're seeing this problem in production, did you rake your assets to build the fingerprinted filenames?

The raked filenames are mangled to something like: /assets/style-4dd5b109ee3439da54f5bdfd78a80473.css, so you can see why using the filename "style.css" will not work.

```
# Rake assets for production
$bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

**Debug**

To me step 1 is making sure your pipeline is setup to serve CSS assets. Until that works, your CSS will be broken. I would ask you to first check on the application.css.erb, to make sure your app includes your CSS tree in the pipeline. Then run the production rake, this will tell you what is happening with your CSS assets. If you post the output to your question, then we could see which, if any CSS is being included in your app.

Required reading for anyone doing Rails apps is the [Asset Pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: My application.css.erb file was working fine, only issue was to link other stylesheets. 

Problem was that config.assests.compile and config.assets.debug were false in my development.erb file. Changing them to true solved my problem.

Comment: Excellent. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "style.css" %>
```

or

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "style" %>
```

Comment: Yes,  it resolved to "/assets/style.css", 
while `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "style.css" %>` was resolving to "stylesheets/style.css", 
I also tried `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    :all %>` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805810/stylesheet-link-tag-all-versus-media-all and it is resolving to "/assets/all.css" .

Comment: Oh no I was just telling what all I have tried. It's still not working though. Only was I'm able to include css is through internal stylesheet.

Comment: Your style.css file is in stylesheets directory right? Or is it in another directory under stylesheets directory

Comment: Its under /app/assets/stylesheets/.

Comment: Then the answer should work, thugh I agree that `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "style" %>` ouputs `"/assets/style.css"` path but still it would work, thats the beauty of asset pipeline. I don't know why thats not working in your case

Answer (score 0):

Go to your config/initializers/assets.rb and include this in the file 'Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( users.css )' , without the quotes, then restart your server.