# Bootstrap on Ruby on Rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

can anyone help me? I already did everything to install Bootstrap on my Ruby on Rails application, however continues to appear without bootstrap format.

I have Rails 4.2.5.1

in gemfile I added, and ran bundle install

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

in app/assets/stylesheets I have application.scss with:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

and in assets/javascript I have application.js with:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Did you rename the *.css files to *.css.sass or .scss?

Comment: yes, it's on "application.scss"

Comment: Do you have some logs? Btw. Sometimes the order of the gems matter. I'm not sure but maybe sass-rails gem should be above the bootstrap-sass gem

Comment: I dont have logs. It's the same if I change the order

Comment: I don't have any errors, the problem is that it continues to appear without the bootstrap format

Comment: Is your `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>` in place in application.html.erb? See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805810/stylesheet-link-tag-all-versus-media-all and [default app](https://railsapps.github.io/rails-default-application-layout.html)

Comment: thanks! that did the trick, I didn't have that. I had to install node.js too, I don't know why

Comment: You are using different version of Bootstrap gem and using bootstrap code of different version.

Answer (score 0):

Please, follow these instructions:

Include following gems in your Gemfile

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', git: 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'less-rails'
```

Run the following commands:

```
bundle
rails g bootstrap:install less
```

Reference: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Comment: It gave me a lot of erros when running that

Comment: bundle gave me a big error report: including this "Errno::ENOENT No such file or directory - git clone "git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git" "

Comment: Just include this in your `Gemfile` and tell me if it works.
`gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'`

Comment: now it gave me this : "Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - git clone "git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git" "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/bundler/git/twitter-bootstrap-rails-6259dce4168c7878cbf2edf620aa1d219f790c05" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet"

Comment: I am using this gem in `ruby -v 1.9.3`. And it is working.

Comment: could it be a problem of my installation of ruby?

Comment: May be, this gem is not compatible with latest ruby version.